# In javasccript - Creating new object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, object

I have a JSON object I'm requiring.

`const tpl = require('../../../../assets/jsons/article-tpl.json');`

then, I'm iterating through an array and I want to use this object to create a new template on every iteration as it is defined in `article-tpl.json`.

```
angular.forEach(content.posts, (val, key) => {
       let _tpl = new Object(tpl);
       // do some things with _tpl
       // push _tpl to array to hold all the different tplts 
    }
});
```

This code does not work.
I get an array of identical templates. Can you help me figure out what the problem is? 
Thanks.

Comment: can you please add some more code or provide a plunker?

Comment: Try the following trick: `let _tpl = JSON.parse(tpl);`

Comment: @AlexM well that actually worked. I used `_tpl = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(tpl));` because it was already an object and not a string. Used lodash `cloneDeep` eventually.

Answer (score 0):

`require` statement is only for node.js, there is no `require` in JavaScript/Angular.

You can load a JSON in Angular using `$http` request (from local) instead of remote download and use it into Angular as you wish.

Example:

```
var myObject = $http.get('myObject.json')
                 .then(
                   function success(res) {
                     return res.data;
                   },
                   function failed(err) {
                     console.log(err)
                   }
                 );
```

`res.data` is an array that you can iterate to extract all you need and use as template.

I use something like this to convert CSV to JSON [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/JuanjoSalvador/4d60cdd75b250340a4b702c9f1193fed).

Comment: You can actually use 'require' on the frontend with browserify (http://browserify.org/) the issue isn't there

Comment: Yeah, right. Is `new Object` the best way for this?

Comment: Didn't mention I'm using webpack. That's why the require

Comment: If you are using webpack... I cannot help then. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

lodash to the rescue.

`let _tpl = _.cloneDeep(tpl);` solves it.

Comment: It's always better to add an explanation to the code you're posting as an answer, so that it will helps visitors understand why this is a good answer.